# Console app created from py2app shows error upon running

Tags: python, py2app

I have a console program and I'm trying to make it run as a .app file. I tried running

```
python3 setup.py py2app --emulate-shell-environment
```

and

```
python3 setup.py py2app
```

and it still gave me this error upon double clicking the .app in /dist

[image]

However, it works by typing this in the terminal

```
/Users/austin/Desktop/WinconCalc/dist/RitoWinconCalculator.app/Contents/MacOS/RitoWinconCalculator
```

This is my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['RitoWinconCalculator.py']

OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'iconfile':'challenger.ico'
}

setup(
    app = APP,
    options = {'py2app' : OPTIONS},
    setup_requires = ['py2app']
)
```

I'm aware that py2app applications are GUI based but is there a way to double click the app to run it through "console mode" like pyinstaller on Windows?

Comment: When you run the app manually, are you within a Python virtualenv? Are there any modules that couldn't be found in the py2app build output?

Comment: Yes, I believe it should be in a venv when being run manually. There aren't any errors when running so all modules seems to be running correctly.